# Tapping a moving animated object

Tags: react-native

I want to write a simple app, where objects move across the screen and the goal is to tap them. I included Animated API in `componentDidMount`:

```
Animated.timing(
  this.state.fadeAnim,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 10000,
  }
).start();
```

Then I would set styles on my React component in `render` method:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setText} >
  <Animated.View style={{
    opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, // Binds directly
    transform: [{
      translateY: this.state.fadeAnim.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [500, 0]  // 0 : 150, 0.5 : 75, 1 : 0
      }),
    }],
  }}>
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110, display: display}}/>
  </Animated.View>    
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The problem is that the Image doesn't react to the tap while it's moving. It does when I tap it's final destination, but the position it's at when it's moving. Could you guys help me with this problem? Or maybe React-Native isn't the best tool for this type of apps and should I move over to native development?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that with react-native. I would suggest using a `<TouchableOpacity>` rather than a `<TouchableHighlight>` to avoid the dark background when pressing the animation.

Also you should wrap the `<TouchableOpacity>` with the animation, not the other way around, otherwise pressing the final position of the animation will also trigger the event.

Here is an example:

```js
<Animated.View style={{
  opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, // Binds directly
  transform: [{
    translateY: this.state.fadeAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [500, 0]  // 0 : 150, 0.5 : 75, 1 : 0
    }),
  }],
}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setText} >
    <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```

You can check [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/event-on-moving-animation) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we can use native driver over here

```
Animated.timing(
  this.state.fadeAnim,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 10000,
    useNativeDriver: true
  }
).start();
```

And the `transform` style should be given to the `TouchableHighlight`.
The problem is that the `Image` is moving but the button is not thus the onClick is not triggered.

```
  <Animated.View style={{
    opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, // Binds directly
    transform: [{
      translateY: this.state.fadeAnim.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [500, 0]  // 0 : 150, 0.5 : 75, 1 : 0
      }),
    }],
  }}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.setText} >
      <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110, display: display}}/>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </Animated.View>
```

This should work. Also react native should be just fine for this.